# How to test set Interval in sinon js

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm trying to write a unit test for `setInterval()`, but i'm not sure how to spy on the `fetchState()`.

maincode.js:

```
var pollStatus = function(interval, killPolling) {
   // Clear Interval if function is called again 
   if (killPolling || StatusPollObj) {
        clearInterval(StatusPollObj);
        StatusPollObj = false;
    }

    // Call once before setInterval Starts
    fetchState();
    StatusPollObj = setInterval(function() {
        if(somecondtion_to_check_inactivity) return;
        fetchState();
    }, interval);
};
```

spec.js

```
 it("state.json setInterval Call",function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    var helper = new state.HELPER();
    var spy = sinon.spy(helper, "fetchState");

    helper.pollStatus('80000', false);
    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
    this.clock.tick(80000);
    expect(spy.called).to.be.true;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spy is not registered to the setInterval. Your function fetchState should be passed as an parameter to the function.

```
var someFun = function(callFunc, interval, killPolling) {
    callFunc();
    StatusPollObj = setInterval(function() {
        if(somecondtion_to_check_inactivity) return;
        callFunc();
    }, interval);
}
```

and your tests should look like this

```
it("state.json setInterval Call",function() {
    this.clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();
    var helper = new state.HELPER();
    var mySpy = sinon.spy(helper, "fetchState");

    helper.pollStatus(mySpy,'80000', false);
    expect(mySpy.called).to.be.true;
    this.clock.tick(80000);
    expect(mySpy.called).to.be.true;
});
```